# Internet Explorer crashes when opening

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, crash, internet-explorer-11

Immediately when I open ie it crashes and shows me this dialog box
[image]

I tried running it with no add-ons like many sites suggest but it doesn't fix the problem. 
Last time I rolled back to ie-8 and the issue was gone but now I need to use ie-11.

Here's the error in the event log:
[image]

How can I get rid of this? Thank you.

Comment: Does the (usually useless) 'Check online for a solution' do anything (did you try it I mean)?

Comment: @DaveRook I've added the error in the event log. Seems there's an issue with the `nvumdshim.dll`. What could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With crashes like this, always check out the Event Log, often it will give a code, a dll or some other clue. In this case, it gives the .dll

`nvumdshim.dll` is related to Nvidia drivers. Try updating Nvidia video card drivers to the latest version.

[Source](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/453-internet-explorer-11-crashes-on-startup-windows-8-1)

Another option is

```
Click the Start button.
Type “nvidia” but don’t press Enter.
In the list of programs that comes up click on “NVIDIA Control Panel”
On the left, click on 3D Settings.
On the right, click the “Program Settings” tab.
Find where it says “1. Select a program to continue” and click on the dropbox box below it, selecting “Microsoft Internet Explorer”.
Click on the dropdown box below it and select the “Integrated graphics” option.
Click the Apply button at the bottom.
```

[Source](http://www.fixkb.com/2012/01/internet-explorer-has-stopped-working-fault-module-name-nvumdshim-dll.html)

This crash is based upon GPU rendering, which was introduced for IE9 (which is why it worked when you rolled back to IE8)

Comment: The second option worked perfectly. Thank you so much :)